# VBA Cancel uploading after specific time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, sharepoint-2013

i have an excel document with some figures. Then a macro generates from different parts of the excel new excel documents.

While this process the documents are uploaded to Sharepoint Libaray and then they should be closed.

Sometimes the upload dialog from excel is not disappearing until you press "cancel" with the mouse or enter.

My thought is that I can close the dialog programmatically after e.g. 5 seconds.
How can I wait for 5 seconds and then simulate the enter key?

Comment: Can you show how you upload the file?

Answer (score 1):

To wait some time you can use `application.wait` more info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656(office.11).aspx and example of use `Application.Wait(Now + #0:00:01#)`

And to simulate ENTER key press, there is method `SendKeys` more info here
http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html. But maybe instead of hitting enter button to close dialog, you can close dialog programmatically.

Or maybe try to use `application.displayalerts = false`